# Label the y-axes in a special way

Tags: plotting, graphics

My plot:

```
Clear[p]
a = 27; b = 1; R = 1;
p[V_, T_] := (R*T/(V - b)) - a*(1/V^2);
LogPlot[Evaluate@Table[p[V, T], {T, {7, 8, 9}}], {V, b, 8}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"T=7", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(c\)]\)=8", 
   "T=9"}, AxesLabel -> {V, p[V, T]}]
```

[image]

My problem is that the y-axes shall be labeled the following way

> $p(V,T)$

But instead of it I get the whole function

> $p(V,T)=\frac{T}{V-1}-\frac{27}{V²}$

Comment: Use `HoldForm[]` or `Defer[]` to prevent evaluation in the label.

Comment: Am I missing something or can you just put string quotes around the label text ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `p[V,T]` is a function and when you call that, Mathematica automatically replaces it by its expression. You have at least two options:

1) `HoldForm[]` prints unevaluated form of the functions:

```
AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[V], HoldForm[p[V, T]]}
```

2) Convert the labels to strings:

```
AxesLabel -> {"V", "p[V, T]"}
```